# Im getting Complie error while using phpword library in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, phpword

Below is code in library file.

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PHPWord.php";
class Word extends PHPWord {
 public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
 }
}
```

Below is the error which i got.

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/app/v1/application//third_party/PHPWord.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/app/v1/application/libraries/Word.php on line 4
```

Mainly because of this

```
(include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
```

I have no idea about it.

Comment: remove extra / from APPPATH."/third_party/PHPWord.php";

make it APPPATH."third_party/PHPWord.php";

Comment: Removed but still same Compile Error

Comment: what is the location of your third_party folder

Comment: /var/www/html/app/v1/application

Comment: try using __DIR__in place of APPPATH

Comment: No use same problem

Comment: set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/usr/share/php5');

write this before using APPPATH